# Error message whenever I add img element to my html

Tags: html, image, console

I am really confused and I do not understand why I am getting the error below whenever I add an img element and I link an image file to it. The path to the image is correct, everything is done locally, the image is displayed without any visual issues. But whenever I open the console I see this error message:

[image]

The weirdest thing is that whenever I open another html file in the same project and I just add ANY image to it just to test, I get the same error, even though I never got that before. This is in Chrome by the way. I also tested in Firefox, Opera, IE, Edge and Safari, but there I see no error messages. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Warcraft III Veto</title>
    <!-- Normalize CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <!-- Main Style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="veto">
    <div class="bar">
        <img src="img/races/human.png">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Vue.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<!-- Main Script -->
<script src="dist/js/veto.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Something else I noticed is that whenever I delete my scipt tags that link to both my script file (which by the way is empty as well as my css), and vue.js, the error message dissapearas. I checked to see if the link to vue was correct and it was. I deleted all files and re-created them, but I still get the error. I am so confused, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be an issue with the version of Chrome.

This should be resolved in the latest update as per the discussion on this [thread](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/6744).

Hope that helps.